# fluid divs with CSS

Tags: html, css

recently I have came across this website, `http://www.zergnet.com/`, and I am really interested to know how they have the `divs` all next to each other even when each one has different height.I tried this code just to generate some random `divs` with different heights, but they all would leave empty space above them. How can I fix this so they would have only 5px from the top?. How can I fix this code to get the same effect as in the website ?

```
    <?php
    for($x = 10; $x > 0; $x--){
    $rand = rand(200, 300);
    echo '<div 
           style="
           margin: 0 5px 10px 5px;
           width:200px; height:'.$rand.'px;
           background-color:red;
           width: 260px;
           float: left;">
<img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" width="260" height="'.$rand.'"></div>';}?>
```

Comment: Would Masonry.js help you? http://masonry.desandro.com

Comment: Is it doable will css only? I was hoping that.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this jquery plugin called [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) It will give the the same layout like you've listed and other cool ones

For css you could create 3 columns and then inside of each parent div create a child div. Like this

```
<div>
   <a href="#">Whatever stuff you want to put in here.</a>
   <a href="#">Whatever stuff you want to put in here.</a>
   <a href="#">Whatever stuff you want to put in here.</a>
   ...and so on and so forth ad nauseum.
</div>
```

css

```
div {
   -moz-column-count: 3;
   -moz-column-gap: 10px;
   -webkit-column-count: 3;
   -webkit-column-gap: 10px;
   column-count: 3;
   column-gap: 10px;
   width: 480px; 
}

div a {
   display: inline-block; /* Display inline-block, and absolutely NO FLOATS! */
   margin-bottom: 20px;
   width: 100%; 
}
```

**example:** http://jsfiddle.net/9x3NX/

Comment: Is there a way to do this with css only?

Answer (score 0):

You can get this layout with HTML and CSS.

Check DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/wxVfj/1/

Your HTML would be...

## HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="item_wrapper">
        <div class="item">...</div>
        <div class="item">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item_wrapper">
        <div class="item">...</div>
        <div class="item">...</div>
        <div class="item">...</div>
        <div class="item">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item_wrapper">
        <div class="item">...</div>
        <div class="item">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:12px;
}
#container {
    float:left;
    width:630px;
    background:green;
}
#container .item_wrapper {
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    margin:0 5px;
}
#container .item {
    width:100%;
    background:#ccc;
    margin:5px 0;
}
```